# Calling System command from Map Reduce

Tags: linux, hadoop, command, mapreduce

I would like to call a system command from my map reduce program.  I want this command to only run once, but it seems as though the command is not recognized.  My test command is:
`hadoop dfs -mv /user/test/somefile1 /user/test/somefile2`

I am issuing the command using:

```
String envp[] = new String[1];
envp[0] = "Path=" + System.getProperty("java.library.path");
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("hadoop fs -mv /user/test/somefile1 /user/test/somefile2", envp);
```

I have two questions,

1. Where is the best place to put this code so it only executes once?
2. Why is the environment where I'm issuing this command not actually running the command?

I have noticed this with other commands as well.

I don't get an error when I issue the hadoop command, but the move does not take place.  If I run the same command from linux command line, it does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some comments:

1. `hadoop dfs -mv` assumes the filesystem for the source and target is hdfs, unless you give schemata in the arguments (e.g., `file:///user/test/somefile1`).
2. If you are running this command from within a Hadoop tool or in Job.configure, say, why spawn a separate process (whose exit code you seem to be ignoring, hence no errors) when you can call it natively in Java like `srcPath.getFileSystem( cfg ).rename( srcPath, dstPath )`?

Comment: In this case, my files are HDFS.

Comment: I would like to issue a System command and it seems as though my environment is not cooperating.  This was just an example, so I won't be using native Java as recommended.  I have tried issuing out to the shell as was recommended by other posters, sh -e `hadoop fs -mv /my/hdfs/file/test.txt /my/hdfs/file/test2.txt`  This also did not yield the results that I expected.

Comment: What is the exit code from the process object?  You can also capture the stderr and stdout of the process object as InputStreams.

Comment: I found tht the Hadoop command was not found.  When I added the fully qualified path to hadoop - /opt/hadoop/bin I was able to issue the command and see the proper results.